# Bounded mismatch with ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>

Tags: java, spring, web-services

i tried to write ServletRegistrationBean method that return
MessageDispatcherServlet instance and i get bounded mismatch error.

this is the method i wrote:

```
public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> requestDispatcher (ApplicationContext conext){
        MessageDispatcherServlet msd = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        msd.setApplicationContext(conext);
        msd.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
servletContext.addServlet("MessageDispatcherServlet",msd);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(msd, "/soap/*");
    }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Please add the dependencies you have in your build file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
 issue by configuring pom file with the next dependancy:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```